# Accessing SQLAlchemy relationship data from Jinja

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am attempting to access data from a related database table and display that in some tables on the front end but struggling to do so. This is what I currently have (reduced to important code).

Database Model:

```
class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Client'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    clientname = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    provider = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    sessions = db.relationship('Session', backref='client')
    contacts = db.relationship('Contact', backref='client')
    region_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Region.region_name'),
            nullable=False)

class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Contact'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    contact_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    contact_phone = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    contact_email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Client.clientname'),
            nullable=False)
```

And then my table containing Jinja templating:

```
<tbody>
      {% for item in client_details %}
          <tr>
         <td>{{ item.clientname }}</td>
         <td>{{ item.contacts.contact_name }}</td>
          </tr>
       {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

And the query I am passing to my render_template:

```
session_details = Session.query.all()
return render_template('tables.session.html', session_details=session_details, passing_alert=passing_alert)
```

Yet I cannot access the Contact.contact_name. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The `contacts` attribute of a `Client` is a collection of `Contact` objects. You have to iterate over it in your template, one way or another. Your query seems unrelated to the rest of your example.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer :

According to @Ilja Everilä comment, as you are using a 1:n relationship, The contact attribute of Client is a collection of contacts objects, and you need to iterate over it like this :

```
<tbody>
      {% for item in client_details %}
          <tr>
         <td>{{ item.client_name }}</td>
         {% for contact in item.contacts %}
         <td>{{ contact.contact_name }}</td>
         {% endfor %}
          </tr>
       {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

And you can render your template like this :

```
def show_infos():
    client_details = Client.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', client_details=client_details)
```